# R: barplot: space between outer bars and the plotting area

Tags: r, plot, graphics, bar-chart

I have a piece of code as below:

```
par(mar=c(0.1, 15, 0.5, 15))
barplot(dat[[1]][, 2], beside=TRUE, axes=FALSE, ylim=ylim.axis_left, space=0, col="#808080")
box()
```

which generatess this plot:
[image]

I want to get rid of the space between the left/right bar and the plotting area, as marked with the box(). I played a little with margins, but it's not the solution, since these shrink the plotting area itself but the space remains...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In absence of reproducible example I took `mtcars` data

```
barplot(mtcars$cyl, axes=FALSE, space=0, col="#808080")
box()
```

[image]

When you set `xaxs` and `yaxs` as below you can notice that the default margin on both side of plot is gone.

```
barplot(mtcars$cyl, axes=FALSE, space=0, col="#808080", xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
box()
```

[image]